# Is this infinite product in $L^1(\mathbb{R}, m)$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, infinite-product

$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right), \hspace{1em} x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}
$$
and $f(0)=1$ to achieve continuity.
$m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

If we guess that $f\in L^1(m)$, then the decay is hard to control.
I have tried the approach of truncating the infinite product to finite products on (geometrically expanding) intervals $\{[3^j\pi/2, 3^{j+1}\pi/2]\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$, but this approach does not give a finite upper bound on $\|f\|_1$.
Similarly, Holder inequality does not give a finite estimate.

Trying the other direction $f\notin L^1(m)$ is also hard.

Comment: This function is the Fourier transform of (the Cantor function shifted to [-1, 0] and flipped along y-axis so that the support is [-1, 1] and the range is [0, 1]).